# Inltk setup "ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterable' from 'collections' (C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\collections\__init__.py)"

Tags: python, installation, deep-learning, nltk, indic

While using iNltk package i ran into this error
`ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterable' from 'collections' (C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\collections\__init__.py)`

I was trying to setup the hindi language

```
from inltk.inltk import setup
setup('hi')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because the `Iterable` abstract class was removed from the `collections` module in Python 3.10. The `inltk` package is still using the old version of the `collections` module, which is why you are getting the error.

There are a few ways to fix this error. One way is to upgrade the `inltk` package to a version that is compatible with Python 3.10. Another way is to manually `import the Iterable class` from the `collections.abc` module.

Or you can make changes in the core file by manually importing the `Iterable` class.
This method is temporary but will save your day.

note: recommended to make this changes if you are using venv(virtual env)

At path `..file_path..\venv\Lib\site-packages\fastai\imports\core.py`

```
from collections import abc,  Counter, defaultdict, namedtuple, OrderedDict
from collections.abc import Iterable
```

make the above changes.

This will import the Iterable class from the collections.abc module, which will allow you to use the inltk package without getting the error.

Another way to fix this error is to downgrade your Python installation to Python 3.9. However, this is not always an option, as some software may not be compatible with Python 3.9.